# Rails dynamic & modifiable form schemas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a problem with forms. I'm developing an application that allows applicants to submit applications, and I want to make sure that users (people who receive those applications) could add/delete questions in their applications. How would I implement that?

My thought is to have a `Application` model and a `ApplicationQuestion` model that `belongs_to` Application. But I'm pretty lost beyond that.

UPDATE:
Another issue is confusing me. In my systems I could get Admins to add/delete ApplicationQuestions dynamically, and I have no problem implementing that. However, I want the Users to see the current set of ApplicationQuestions and answer them without being able to add/delete/edit questions. I'm now using a proxy model ApplicationQuestionAnswer which belongs_to Application and ApplciationQuestion. However I'm still having trouble with the views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can keep the models as you are thinking. There will be a `User` model which would have two roles basically. One would be the `teacher` (just taking an example) who asks the questions and one would be `student` who will answer those questions. Now the `teacher` would be able to create `application` having different `questions` so two more models `Application` and `ApplicationQuestion`. The relations can be:

```
Application belongs_to User
ApplicationQuestion belongs to Application
```

Now the `student` will answer the questions which can be stored in `answer` table which would be another model `ApplicationQuestionAnswer` which would also belong to `User` and `ApplicationQuestion`. Now the questions can be of different type (numeric, string, date etc) so take care of that, they all can be stored in a single column by handling it at the code end and for this also have a `question_type` attribute in the `ApplicationQuestion` model.

Now the `teacher` can edit the `application` and delete the questions if they want or add new. Be sure to add dependent destroy so the answer would also be deleted when the question is deleted. Also suppose if the `question` can have `choices` then be sure to add one more model `ApplicationQuestionChoice` which would belong to `ApplicationQuestion` and its `id` will be saved as the `answer` of the `student`.

**Update:**

The `ApplicationQuestionAnswer` model will save each `question`'s answer instead what you can do is that have two models. One would be `ApplicationAnswer` and another `ApplicationQuestionAnswer`. And the associations would be:

```
ApplicationAnswer belongs_to User
ApplicationAnswer belongs_to Application
ApplicationQuestionAnswer belongs_to ApplicationAnswer
```

Now in the view the `form` would be for creating/updating `ApplicationAnswer` and having `nested forms` for its associated `ApplicationQuestionAnswer` which you will display to the students. And this will save all the answers.

Also the same nested forms can be used with the `teacher` to add or remove questions. You can also use any gem for nested form too:

- [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)
- [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm actually more concerned about the views. How should I render the forms to form-fillers?

Comment: note that `nested_form` gem is abandoned (last activity in 2013)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm actually more concerned about the views. How should I render the
>   forms to form-fillers?

Start with an `Application` form containing a stable amount of `Questions` (refer to [Rails nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) to implement it). The basic implementation could look like that:

```
<%= form_for @application do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :application_questions do |aq_form| %>            
        <%= aq_form.text_field :question %>
        <%= aq_form.text_field :question %>
```

Dynamic adding and removing questions could be achieved by adding (and removing) `HTML` blocks produced by `Rails` helpers shown above:

```
<%= aq_form.text_field :question %>
```

You could dig into it's implementation by yourself (and write some `javascript` to orchestrate `HTML` blocks addition/removement) or use some gem with that functionality. One of those popular solutions is [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon). It provides you with pretty links (`link_to_add_association` and `link_to_remove_association`), which being clicked perform the desired dynamic actions. You may be intrested in trying a [cocoon demo application](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo) to get an idea of how to embed it into your project.

Comment: Well...I have another question that's confusing me (or perhaps I did not get your answer). In my systems I could get `Admin`s to add/delete `ApplicationQuestion`s dynamically, and I have no problem implementing that. However, I want the `User`s to see the current set of `ApplicationQuestion`s and answer them without being able to add/delete/edit questions. I'm now using a proxy model `ApplicationQuestionAnswer` which `belongs_to` `Application` and `ApplciationQuestion`. However I'm still having trouble with the views.